# R: How to split a character string containing commas according to comma

Tags: r, split, character

Example

```
string <- "field1,field2,\"there is a , in field3\", field4, \"2,456\", field6"
```

A negative attempt:

```
test <- unlist(strsplit(noquote(string), ","))
test <- gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9' ']", "", test)
gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", test)

[1] "field1"     "field2"     "there is a" "in field3" 
[5] "field4"     "2"          "456"        "field6"
```

Note that fields containing commas are between `\" ... \"`.

Comment: whats your ideal result?

Comment: Try read.table(text=string, sep=","). It will ignore commas inside quotation marks. It works on your example.

Comment: I love simple answers :-) 
If you convert it to an answer, I'll accept it!
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for offering, I'm a sucker for stackoverflow's gamification of advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read.table function will ignore commas inside quotation marks.

```
string <- "field1,field2,\"there is a , in field3\", field4, \"2,456\", field6"

desired_result <- read.table(text=string, sep=",")
```